# Generate dynamic DATA variables with VUE array

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to define dynamic variables for `VUE`, and then use them in`v-for`. when I load the page they work, but if they change their values later, the values in the view do not change anymore.

`VUE`

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#mainCreate',
    data: {
        modules : [],
        feature: []
    },
});
```

I am using this function to generate the variables within `feature`:

```js
    function creatDataFeatures() {
        $.each(app.modules, function(index,module){
            app.feature[index] = module.features;
        });
    }
```

So I'm loading it in the view:

```html
<table class="table table-striped mt-3">
   <tbody>
      <tr v-for="feat in feature[index]">
           <td>
              <input type="checkbox" checked>
          </td>
           <td>
              @{{feat.title}}
           </td>
           <td class="text-info">
              @{{feat.price ? '$ '+feat.price : '$ 0'}}
           </td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

When loading the page I load the data correctly, but if I then change the ejm values: `feature [index] = [other array]` (I change it for the same data format as the start ones) in the view does not change anything. a solution or an alternative would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `app.feature[index] = module.features;` falls into limitation of Vue regarding arrays.

To fix, use:

```js
    $.each(app.modules, function(index,module){
        Vue.set(app.feature, index, module.features); // changed this line
    });
```

See [Vue - Array Change Detection - Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats):

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue **cannot** detect the following
> changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> 2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`
>
> To overcome caveat 1, both of the following will accomplish the same
> as `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`, but will also trigger state
> updates in the reactivity system:
>
> ```
> // Vue.set
> Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
> ```